# Word finder using pygame

Tags: python, performance, recursion, pygame

I made a word searching app that allows the user to inout words into a text box,
and parts of the word grid will be highlighted to show the location of the words.
The letters of the grid can be edited while you are using it by clicking on the cell,
and pressing the key you want to replace the current letter with.

Here is how it goes:

[image]

I made this recursive function to find each word:

```
    def adj(self, c, idx, lstlst, wrd):
        x, y = self.cells.index(c) % self.cols, self.cells.index(c) // self.cols
        x1, x2 = max(0, x - 1), min(x + 2, self.cols + 2)
        y1, y2 = max(0, y - 1), min(y + 2, self.rows + 2)
        adjs = [cell for row in self.grid[y1:y2] for cell in row[x1:x2] if cell != c]
        taillst = lstlst[-1]
        for cell in adjs:
            if len(wrd) > idx:
                if cell.text == wrd[idx] and cell not in taillst:
                    lstlst.append(taillst[:] + [cell])
                    self.adj(cell, idx+1, lstlst, wrd)
```

This is how I called it:

```
        elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            grid.type(event)
            word.type(event)
            for cell in grid.cells:
                cell.color = (0, 0, 0)
            for cell in grid.cells:
                lstlst = [[cell]]
                grid.adj(cell, 1, lstlst, word.text)
                for lst in lstlst:
                    if ''.join([c.text for c in lst]) == word.text:
                        for c in lst:
                            c.color = (255, 0, 0)
```

I know, it's a mess, but I am trying. Despite that, can you show me **how can I improve the efficiency of my word-searching algorithim?**

Here is my entire code:

```
import pygame

pygame.font.init()
wn = pygame.display.set_mode((600, 600))

letters = \
'''
KJDJCIOSDZ
PGRIWOTAID
VETVALCGLS
OFZESGZASW
SOYRBKOADL
FUWTQOXNGE
CILIWMEPAV
NEZCJRVZNL
GXZAOQMFIG
EUPLIESCGP
HORIZONTAL
'''

class Cell():
    def __init__(self, x, y, s, text='', color=(0, 0, 0), cell=True):
        self.input_box = pygame.Rect(x, y, s, s)
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.s = s
        self.w = s
        self.color_inactive = color
        self.color_active = pygame.Color('purple')
        self.color = self.color_inactive
        self.text = text
        self.active = False
        self.pad = 10
        self.cell = cell
        self.font = pygame.font.Font(None, s)

    def check_status(self, pos):
        if self.input_box.collidepoint(pos):
            self.active = not self.active
        else:
            self.active = False
        self.color = self.color_active if self.active else self.color_inactive

    def type(self, event):
        if self.active:
            if self.cell:
                if event.unicode and event.unicode.lower() in 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz ':
                    self.text = event.unicode
            else:
                if event.key == pygame.K_BACKSPACE:
                    self.text = '' if len(self.text) < 2 else self.text[:-1]
                elif event.unicode and event.unicode.lower() in 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz ':
                    self.text += event.unicode 
            
    def draw(self):
        txt = self.font.render(self.text, True, self.color)
        if not self.cell:
            width = max(self.w, txt.get_width())
            self.input_box.w = width + self.pad * 2
            x = self.x + self.pad
        else:
            x = self.x+(self.s-txt.get_width())//2
        y = self.y+(self.s-txt.get_height())*5//7
        wn.blit(txt, (x, y))
        pygame.draw.rect(wn, self.color, self.input_box, 2)

class Grid():
    def __init__(self, x, y, size, letters, color=(0, 0, 0)):
        rows = len(letters)
        cols = len(letters[0])
        self.grid =  [[Cell(i*size+x, j*size+y, size, letter) for i, letter in enumerate(row)] for j, row in enumerate(letters)]
        self.cells = [cell for row in self.grid for cell in row]
        self.rows = rows
        self.cols = cols

    def check_status(self, pos):
        for cell in self.cells:
            cell.check_status(pos)

    def type(self, event):
        for cell in self.cells:
            cell.type(event)

    def adj(self, c, idx, lstlst, wrd):
        x, y = self.cells.index(c) % self.cols, self.cells.index(c) // self.cols
        x1, x2 = max(0, x - 1), min(x + 2, self.cols + 2)
        y1, y2 = max(0, y - 1), min(y + 2, self.rows + 2)
        adjs = [cell for row in self.grid[y1:y2] for cell in row[x1:x2] if cell != c]
        taillst = lstlst[-1]
        for cell in adjs:
            if len(wrd) > idx:
                if cell.text == wrd[idx] and cell not in taillst:
                    lstlst.append(taillst[:] + [cell])
                    self.adj(cell, idx+1, lstlst, wrd)

    def draw(self):
        for cell in self.cells:
            cell.draw()

grid = Grid(50, 70, 32, list(filter(None, letters.split('\n'))))
word = Cell(50, 20, 32, cell=False)

while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
        elif event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            grid.check_status(event.pos)
            word.check_status(event.pos)
        elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            grid.type(event)
            word.type(event)
            for cell in grid.cells:
                cell.color = (0, 0, 0)
            for cell in grid.cells:
                lstlst = [[cell]]
                grid.adj(cell, 1, lstlst, word.text)
                for lst in lstlst:
                    if ''.join([c.text for c in lst]) == word.text:
                        for c in lst:
                            c.color = (255, 0, 0)

    wn.fill((255, 255, 255))
    grid.draw()
    word.draw()
    pygame.display.flip()
```